# Modifying an open source program?

Tags: c, visual-studio-2008, open-source

I would consider myself a fairly competent programmer with experience in Java and VB.net. My latest swim around the programming lake is having me modify a program written in C. (The program is Wireshark, an open source network analyzing tool.) I followed the instructions here http://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsdg_html_chunked/ChSetupWin32.html and simply don't know where to go from there. I'd like to use Visual Studio 2008 to work with the code if possible, but will do whatever is necessary. (I'm a total noob at using command prompt to do anything though.)

Comment: How familiar are you with C? Sorry to be sounding belittling but I am not. It's just a question that you should ask yourself. Are you sure you can do this, as by the sound of it, you are throwing yourself into the deep end...

Comment: Not at all familiar. :) I'm reading books and introducing myself, I just wanted to get this set up so its there when I'm ready to dive in. I do have some sort of an idea of what I'm getting myself into.

Comment: ok...the best of luck and shoot questions around here or click on the C tags to get questions pertaining to C and it will help you also. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you followed those steps, then you've built it.  I'll copy [Section 2.2.10](http://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsdg_html_chunked/ChSetupWin32.html) here.

> **2.2.10. Build Wireshark**
>
> Now it's time to build Wireshark ...
>
> 1. If you've closed **cmd.exe** in the meantime, prepare **cmd.exe** again
> 2. **nmake -f Makefile.nmake all** to build Wireshark
> 3. wait for Wireshark to compile - this may take a while!
> 4. run **C:\wireshark\wireshark-gtk2\wireshark.exe** and check if it starts

Just make changes in the code, do these steps over again, and *presto!* you've modified the program.  You may want to bone up on [C debuggers](http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) if you're doing anything very complicated.

Comment: Ah I see. Its the simple things that elude me at times, that and I'm used to just clicking a compile button and seeing if it works or not. :) Thanks for the link as well, I think that'll help me.